# Detecting Collision using Bounding Box

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I am new to cocos2d-x and i am developing a game using cocos2d-x in xcode. In my game I added player sprite and Obstacle sprite. Obstacle sprite is moving continuously from right to left.
Now i am trying to add collision between the two sprites. So that I am using bounding box.Following is my code. but it is not working. this is first time that i am using bounding box.

```
if(obs1->boundingBox().intersectsRect(man->boundingBox()))
{
    obs1->stopAllActions();
}
```

I created both the sprite in init() function and declare the above code in init function. Please help me to solve this.

Comment: There is no need to add tags in the title, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles. Please do not add it back again

Comment: Sorry, I am new to Stack Overflow here after i will not add tags to my questions.

Comment: Welcome to SO :-) it's perfectly OK to add tags to your questions. But use the 'tags' input field for that instead of the question title

Comment: They both have same parent ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should be using `if xxx->containsPoint()`